# kable_styling with full_width = T in a tint document

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, tint, kableextra

I have the following `tint` PDF document:

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: tint::tintPdf
---

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(A = runif(10), 
                 B = runif(10), 
                 C = runif(10), 
                 D = runif(10),
                 E = runif(10),
                 F = runif(10),
                 G = runif(10),
                 H = runif(10))

# Print as a table
knitr::kable(df, booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex", 
             caption = "This is a caption in the margin.") 
```
````

This produces a PDF with the following table:

[image]

The table is wide and spills out over the caption. To avoid this, I can specify it's a full width table using `full_width = TRUE` in the `kable_styling` function of `kableExtra`.

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: tint::tintPdf
---

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(A = runif(10), 
                 B = runif(10), 
                 C = runif(10), 
                 D = runif(10),
                 E = runif(10),
                 F = runif(10),
                 G = runif(10),
                 H = runif(10))

# Print as a table
knitr::kable(df, booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex", 
             caption = "This is a caption in the margin.") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)
```
````

This gives the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Environment tabu undefined.
>
> Error: Failed to compile Test.tex. See Test.log for more info.
>   Execution halted

It seems to be upset about the `tabu` package (or lack thereof). So, I add in this package in my YAML, like so:

```
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: tint::tintPdf
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tabu}
---
```

This runs, but produces the following:

[image]

Now, the contents of the table overlaps. Humpf. Even if I include `fig.fullwidth = TRUE` in the chunk options I have no luck.

How do I produce a full width table in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround. By specifying `longtable = TRUE` in `kable`, the caption is bumped to the top. Also, in the YAML: `tables: yes`. Counterintuitively, using `kable_styling` with `full_width = TRUE` will squish the table into the full width of the main body and **not** the main body + margin.

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: tint::tintPdf
tables: yes
---

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(A = runif(10), 
                 B = runif(10), 
                 C = runif(10), 
                 D = runif(10),
                 E = runif(10),
                 F = runif(10),
                 G = runif(10),
                 H = runif(10))

# Print as a table
knitr::kable(df, booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex", longtable = TRUE,
             caption = "This is a caption in the margin.") 
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, we need more people who answer to their topic when they find the answer :)